# Is there a way to send data from a Dynamic Object like and ID?

Tags: delphi, pascal

So I have to create a piece of software much like Instagram or 9Gag where if an Upvote button is pressed I would like to use the Post_ID and the User_ID to add to an Upvote table in my database. As the Panels that are being created dynamically are the parents of the buttons I would like to use that data but the OnClick event can only accept 1 parameter. Can anyone help.

To correct myself, I am using images instead of buttons and usually I would have used the caption of the button to store the data but I can't with an TImage.

```pascal
procedure dynImgUpvoteClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
showmessage('Clicked');
end;

dynImgUpvote.OnClick := dynImgUpvoteClick;
```

I want to write it so that when the button is clicked I can send the Post_ID and User_ID to use with SQL to add to the database. I however can't use more than one parameter.

Comment: Most Delphi controls have a Tag property where you can store a nativeint value.

Comment: Maybe use the name instead, assuming that all your components are named? ( (Sender as TImage).Name)

Comment: @Brian, that only allows me to have one parameter because only integer values get accepted and there is no way to combine to values and then when trying to extract it again to differentiate between the post_ID and user_ID

Comment: A pointer (eg to an object) is a nativeint so you can store an object reference in a Tag field.

Comment: @Dsm It worked, thanks. How will I do it with a string value though?

Comment: Probably the Luddite way is to define an object with a string property. A string has an address too, though. I prefer the former, in case I need to add any extra properties later.

Comment: Where do the Post_ID and User_ID come from when an image is clicked? How does the image know what Post_ID and User_ID should be used? There are most likely ways to accomplish what you want to do, if it was actually clear what you're trying to do. You cannot modify the signature of a `TNotify` event (which is what an `OnClick` event is), but there are methods to get info in that event. Without knowing what specifically you're trying to accomplish, it's very hard to suggest how to do so.

Comment: @KenWhite , I have a while not Eof loop that loops through the records of my database. And At each record a dynamic panel gets created with a dynamic image on and dynamic buttons so that it looks like an instagram post. All those posts are placed on a scroll box so you can scroll through them. Now, on each 'post' there is a button to upvote the post and when that button is clicked, I want to know what post is being liked and who is liking that post.

Comment: You ignored my question. *Where do the Post_ID and User_ID come from when an image is clicked?* I understand that you're dynamically creating the images and buttons, but **when that button is clicked, how do you know which Post_ID and User_ID are to be used?** I asked that question twice in my previous comment, and you ignored both of them to repeat what you've already said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the following sugestions:

1. Usage of `Tag` property is a bad form and not advised in general.
2. You can ever create a descendant class containing as many properties as you wish:
   For instance:

```pascal
type TMyImage = class(TImage)
      strict private
        FStrParam: string;
        FIntParam: Integer;
      public
        property StrParam: string read FStrParam write FStrParam;
        property IntParam: string read FIntParam write FIntParam;
      end;
```

Then you dynamically create your images with all necessary properties set:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Img: TMyImage;
begin
  Img := TMyImage.Create(Self);
  {Set other properties: size, positipn etc.}
  Img.StrParam := 'Some string';
  Img.IntParam := 123;
  Img.OnClick := dynImgUpvoteClick;
end;
```

and process any properties in your type OnClick handler:

```
procedure dynImgUpvoteClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  showmessage('Clicked ' + (Sender as TMyImage).StrParam +
    IntToStr((Sender as TMyImage).IntParam));
end;
```